# In Amazon Connect Contact Flow, how can you configure a delay between when agent is connected, and when conversation starts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Can this kind of delay be designed into an Amazon Connect Contact Flow?

1. Call is routed to agent.
2. Recorded message is played AFTER call is routed to said agent.
3. Contact Event with event type of CONNECTED is dispatched.
4. Actual conversation starts.

The idea here is program a delay into the Contact Flow so that the Contact Event with CONNECTED status arrives before the actual conversation starts.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an Agent whisper flow or a Customer whisper flow, depending on who you want the message played to, then use the Set whisper flow block to select the flow you just created.